# how to change from $.getJson to $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
function getPopulate() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/products' + document.getElementById("inputproduct").value, function (json) {
        document.getElementById('content-wrap').innerHTML = compiledTemplate(json);
    });
};
getPopulate();
```

but since i need to add headers authorization, i have to use $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://localhost:3000/products", 
    headers: { authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password) },
    // ...
```

What i have to do to complete the rest of the code?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there, you just need to append the value to the URL and add a `success` handler to execute when the request completes:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://localhost:3000/products" + $('#inputproduct').val(), 
    headers: { authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password) },
    success: function(json) {
       $('#content-wrap').html(compiledTemplate(json));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `headers`, as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/products",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
    },
    . . . .  
});
```